# Stop hover effect on an anchor tag within a <div> with a class using CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

All the links on my page have text-decoration: underline when hovered but I am trying to select anchor tags in my div with a class of logo and give it a text-decoration: none;
So essentially I want all links on my page to be underlined when hovered except for the .logo
Is there something I'm missing here with selecting pseudo classes? Or something else entirely.
Could you also please take the time to briefly explain why ".logo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;}" doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
    <h3><a href="#heroSection">My Name</a></h3>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#aboutSection">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#websitesSection">Websites</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projectsSection">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contactSection">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#resumeSection">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

The CSS is as follows

```
a:link{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

a:visited{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.logo a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: did you try -> text-decoration: none !important;

Comment: It's working fine though: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/182/

Comment: It is working fine, **note**: only `<a href="#heroSection">My Name</a>` is inside `.logo`

Answer (score 1):

I used the sample code you provided and it works as intended!
You can try **Empty Cache and Hard Reload** then test it again.

> To hard reload in google chrome you need to first be in developer mode (F12) then you simply
>   right-click on the reload button and select Empty Cache and Hard
>   Reload.

If your browser is caching your scripts then all of your updates may not be reflected on your test page in a timely manner.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I've tried this, also disabled the cache, inspected the element, used !important, run it through CSSLint to see if there's anything wrong with the css that might effect this and it's still underlined when I hover. Is there anything else you could think of that that would be worth checking?

Comment: I can recall a few times in the past where i had to restart both my Apache Server (WAMP) and my web editor (DreamWeaver) before things worked as they should. When ever a problem persists and you are sure that there is no reason for the problem to be there... a nice computer restart does wonders.  

I have been in your position before, i can assure you that (this time) the problem is not your code.